# Not in scope 'foldrl'

Tags: haskell, module, scope

When trying to define the function

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
maximum' = foldrl (\x acc -> if x > acc then x else acc)
```

ghci reports the error:

```
Not in scope: `foldrl'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Ubuntu 10.04
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
```

Why isn't the function `foldrl` in scope?

Comment: Why do you believe a function called `foldrl` exists?

Comment: A search on SO for `foldrl` didn't turn up anything else relevant, so I added a real question in case anyone else tries this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ohhh, you want `foldr1` not `foldrl`, the last character is a `1`, not an `l`

Comment: Sorry, It is foldr1! No problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean `foldr1` (last character is the digit `1`), not `foldrl`.